# How can I take a picture in an app created with Kivy in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, camera, kivy

I am creating a mobile application for the iPhone using kivy. I use the following kv file:

### app.kv

```
...
            Camera:
                id: camera
                resolution: (640, 480)
                play: True
            Button:
...
```

When I attempt to run this application on my iPad, it fails:

### log

```
CRITICAL          ] [Camera      ] Unable to find any valuable Camera provider at all!
avfoundation - ImportError: No module named camera_avfoundation
File "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/3A4C2631-1EF2-4414-A7FA-0F1744B50376/simpliedhome.app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 57, in core_select_lib
fromlist=[modulename], level=0)

opencv - ImportError: No module named cv
File "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/3A4C2631-1EF2-4414-A7FA-0F1744B50376/simpliedhome.app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/__init__.py", line 57, in core_select_lib
fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
File "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/3A4C2631-1EF2-4414-A7FA-0F1744B50376/simpliedhome.app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/camera/camera_opencv.py", line 20, in <module>
import cv
```

Some basic research suggests that kivy might not support the ios camera. I have investigated two other paths aside from native camera support in Kivy. I have checked out pyobjus and it seems promising but requires more knowledge of native ios than I possess at current. I also looked at pyler which lacks support for iOS. Has someone got the iOS camera working with a kivy app?